# VM Periodic Task Thread, VM Thread and WebSphere MQ Trace Monitor consume 100+% cpu in linux

Tags: java, linux, nio, vmware, ibm-mq

My standalone java application uses nio selector for socket connection, ibm mq classes (version 7.0.1.3) to listen queue and topic and ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER for db.Three different thread running for socket ,queue and topic connection. queue and topic listener are working in asynchronous mode. I make runnable jar in eclipse mars, Oracle jdk version 1.7.03. when I start application in my window system(64-bit,16gb ram,intel core-i7) its working fine, its consume about 0.3% of cpu. but when I start application in VMware IDE CDR10 run on linux (64 bit).it consume 90-120% CPU. openJDK version install in VM is 1.7.0_03-icedtea(64-bit).

Suspects for high CPU use after stack analysis

1. VM Periodic Task Thread - consume 40-50 % of cpu
2. VM Thread - consume 25-30% of cpu
3. WebSphere MQ Trace Monitor- consume 25-30% cpu.

Questions:

1. Why thread 1, and 2 consume high cpu and how to optimize it.?
2. how to stop thread 3, is it impact on functionality of JMS.?
3. Is any need to change configuration of VMware to run java application?
4. Is nio selector cause the high cpu consumption?

Thanks you in advance.
below is my stacktrace using jstack command.
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode):

```
"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d1c001000 nid=0x1280 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c007000 nid=0xc47 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ServerThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c3b0800 nid=0xcd7 runnable [0x00007f1d13b76000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:228)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:81)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x00000000ee0f17e8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
        - locked <0x00000000ee0f17d8> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000000ee0f09a8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:102)


"RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection[qmid=ADS.QUEUE.MANAGER_2014-03-19_11.32.54           ,fap=10,peer=ads1sitsvr1/10.106.95.15,localport=43233,ssl=no]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d00001800 nid=0xcb1 runnable [0x00007f1d13c77000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.receive(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1409)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.receiveBuffer(RemoteRcvThread.java:737)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.receiveOneTSH(RemoteRcvThread.java:701)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteRcvThread.run(RemoteRcvThread.java:146)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:298)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1220)

"JMSCCThreadPoolMaster" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c4e3000 nid=0xcaf in Object.wait() [0x00007f1d38159000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ee101cf8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:651)
        - locked <0x00000000ee101cf8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.waitForNotification(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:621)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$WorkQueueManagerThread.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:887)

"WebSphere MQ Trace Monitor" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c31e800 nid=0xc77 sleeping[0x00007f1d40305000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.commonservices.internal.utils.TraceMonitor.run(TraceMonitor.java:123)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c128800 nid=0xc70 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c126000 nid=0xc6e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c123000 nid=0xc6b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c121000 nid=0xc6a runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c0cc000 nid=0xc5f in Object.wait() [0x00007f1d40ebe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ee158730> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
        - locked <0x00000000ee158730> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c0c9800 nid=0xc5e in Object.wait() [0x00007f1d40fbf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000ee158760> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x00000000ee158760> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c0c1000 nid=0xc5c runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c011800 nid=0xc4d runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c013800 nid=0xc4f runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f1d3c133000 nid=0xc72 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 273
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you've determined the thread cpu consumption stats. Plus have thought about updating MQ client libraries. 7.0.1 is quite old now. Newer ones do have backwards compatibility to apps and the queue manners

Comment: with top and shif+h ..i get the thread with statics.... convert pid  to hex code and identify the thread in stack trace... i disable MQ functionality..still it consuming 60-70% CPU...

Comment: I'm not offering this as an answer because there may be requirements to keep running the old version MQ classes, but there are several high-CPU apars in the **10** Fix Packs since v7.0.1.3 as well as many security vulnerabilities.  Your *best* option is to upgrade to v8.0 client classes (which by the way have an IBM-supported Jar-only installation) and see if the problem doesn't go away.  If not, at least IBM will support you on that version. (v7.0.1 is End of Life as of 30 September 2015.)  But to debug high CPU for MQ it would *really* help to know which specific processes are racing.

Comment: hello virendra, were you able to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the Late Response ,   the main culprit was the GC thread, the heap space was low in system so GC running very frequently..